# how to identify if the MenuBarExtra in macos is hidden by the system

Tags: macos, menubar, menubarextra

I was reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/the-menu-bar#Menu-bar-extras) apple documentation for MenuBarExtra in macos and it states:

> When necessary, the system hides menu bar extras to make room for app
> menus. Similarly, if there are too many menu bar extras, the system
> may hide some to avoid crowding app menus.

I am using Appkit implementation for MenuBarExtras and wanted to know, how to identify if the system has hidden/unhidden my menuBarExtra. Is there some event that is received when the system hides it?

Comment: I'm aware of some solutions for AppKit status bar items, but none for SwiftUI's `MenuBarExtra`

Comment: Can u share the solution, as I m having the Appkit MenuBarExtra.

Comment: Did you have a reaction to my answer? Please consider marking it as accepted if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need a reference to the `NSWindow` that holds that status item. You can get that like this:

```
statusItem.button?.window
```

Then, you'll want to listen to some `NSNotification`s related to that window. For example, we listen to:

```
NSWindow.didChangeScreenNotification
NSWindow.didMoveNotification
NSWindow.didResizeNotification
NSWindow.didChangeOcclusionStateNotification
```

Theoretically, only the last one should be required (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419549-didchangeocclusionstatenotificat), actually, but we have some use cases for the others as well.

Then, upon receiving the notification, you can check the occlusion by doing:

```
window.occlusionState.contains(.visible)
```